# Connecting Array Index with Linked List

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to implement Bucket Sort in Java without using Collections framework, on my own. I have a problem in implementing it.

I wanted to store a list of elements in a particular array index.

For Ex:

```
arr[0]={1,2,3,4}; //Here Array index 0 will be storing 4 values.
```

So I chose to have a linked list to store those values and then to map the array index with that linked list.

But I am not aware of how to map an Array index to a Linked List.

For Ex:

```
arr[0]->LinkedList1
arr[2]->LinkedList2
// ... and so on
```

Please suggest how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, arrays or Collections are simply a collection of objects of the same type. So, for your requirement, what you need is an array of lists.

```
List[] arrayOfLists = {};
```

This creates an array whose each member is a list (You can also create an array of LinkedList if you like).
Now, create a LinkedList and assign it to index 0 of the array.

```
LinkedList list1 = new LinkedList();
arrayOfLists[0] = list1;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @pranushagarwal i need to implement without using Collection framework

Comment: @Yuvaraj then you cannot use the java linkedlists at all. The only list of elements that remains is an array. Otherwise, create your own class implementing a linked list structure.